# Additional custom dimensions for products in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, dimensions

I have a products with the following size parameters:

- Length (Woocomerce standard)
- Width (Woocomerce standard)
- Height (Woocomerce standard)
- **Diameter**
- **Thickness**
- **Circuit**

In the product edit page I have only Length, Width, Height (Woocomerce standard)

I would like to add my **other sizes parameters**

How can I add this extra sizes properly?

Is there any filter for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is multiple ways…

**1) Using Product attributes:** (without any coding need):

- You should create 3 new product attributes *(one for each other missing dimension)*. 
  [image]
- You should set each of them in each product with the correct options (displayed on products option) and values. 
  [image]

**Advantage:** Those other dimention attributes will be displayed on product pages.

**Disadvantages:**

- Each attribute Needs to be set for each product and each value is going to be a term of this product attribute.
- There are no specific existing `WC_Product` methods to get those custom product attributes like the default dimension ones. So is going to be more complicated to get them outside the product page.

---

**2) Using custom setting fields:**

```
// Add custom fields to product shipping tab
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_dimensions', 'add_product_options_other_dimensions');
function add_product_options_other_dimensions(){
    global $product_object;

    $product_id = method_exists( $product_object, 'get_id' ) ? $product_object->get_id() : $product_object->id;

    echo '</div><div class="options_group">'; // New option group

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'          => '_diameter',
        'label'       => __( 'Diameter', 'woocommerce' ),
        'desc_tip'    => 'true',
        'description' => __( 'Diameter description help.', 'woocommerce' )
    ) );

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'          => '_thickness',
        'label'       => __( 'Thickness', 'woocommerce' ),
        'desc_tip'    => 'true',
        'description' => __( 'Thickness description help.', 'woocommerce' )
    ) );

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'          => '_circuit',
        'label'       => __( 'Circuit', 'woocommerce' ),
        'desc_tip'    => 'true',
        'description' => __( 'Circuit description help.', 'woocommerce' )
    ) );

}

// Save the custom fields values as meta data
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_product_options_other_dimensions' );
function save_product_options_other_dimensions( $post_id ){

    if( isset( $_POST['_diameter'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_diameter', esc_attr( $_POST['_diameter'] ) );

    if( isset( $_POST['_thickness'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_thickness', esc_attr( $_POST['_thickness'] ) );

    if( isset( $_POST['_circuit'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_circuit', esc_attr( $_POST['_circuit'] ) );

}

// Add custom fields to product variation settings
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes','add_variation_options_other_dimensions', 10, 3 );
function add_variation_options_other_dimensions( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ){

    $variation_diameter = get_post_meta($variation->ID,"_diameter", true );
    if( ! $variation_diameter ) $variation_diameter = "";

    $variation_thickness = get_post_meta($variation->ID,"_thickness", true );
    if( ! $variation_thickness ) $variation_thickness = "";

    $variation_circuit = get_post_meta($variation->ID,"_circuit", true );
    if( ! $variation_circuit ) $variation_circuit = "";

    echo '<p class="form-field dimensions_field">';

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'          => '_diameter' . '_' . $loop,
        'label'       => __( 'Diameter', 'woocommerce' ),
        'desc_tip'    => 'true',
        'description' => __( 'Diameter description help.', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value'       => $variation_diameter
    ) );

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'          => '_thickness' . '_' . $loop,
        'label'       => __( 'Thickness', 'woocommerce' ),
        'desc_tip'    => 'true',
        'description' => __( 'Thickness description help.', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value'       => $variation_thickness
    ) );

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'          => '_circuit' . '_' . $loop,
        'label'       => __( 'Circuit', 'woocommerce' ),
        'desc_tip'    => 'true',
        'description' => __( 'Circuit description help.', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value'       => $variation_circuit
    ) );

    echo '</p>';
}


// Save product variation custom fields values
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation','save_variation_options_other_dimensions', 10 ,2 );
function save_variation_options_other_dimensions( $variation_id, $loop ){

    $built_lenght = $_POST["_diameter_$loop"];
    if( isset($built_lenght) )
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_built_lenght', esc_attr($built_lenght) );

    $built_width = $_POST["_thickness_$loop"];
    if( isset($built_width) )
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_built_width', esc_attr($built_width) );

    $built_height = $_POST["_circuit_$loop"];
    if( isset($built_height) )
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_built_height', esc_attr($built_height) );
}
```

This code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).

You will get that for products:

[image]

And that for product variations (in variable products "variations settings):

[image]

Now to display and get those values, you will have to [override the woocommerce template via your theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) as explained in this documentation.

The file to copy and override via your theme is: `single-product/product-attributes.php` template.

You will have to add some code to it to display your custom additional dimension labels and values just after the displayed default dimentions.

To output the correct values you will use `get_post_meta()` function.

For example to display the `diameter` value you will use:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_diameter', true ); ?>
```

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec, is there any way they can act like Woocommerce attributes? I mean to use them for filtering? or even a link included with them self? because as I saw they went to the  wp_postmeta table, not wp_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies

Answer (score 0):

You can use [custom_fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) or [product attributes](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/) for this.