# Woocommerce include custom dimension into $product class

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, dimension

**Situation:** A Woocommerce product object typically holds an array `dimensions` with raw x y z values.

```
$product = [
  'dimensions' => [
    'length' => 1,
    'width' => 1,
    'height' => 1
  ],
  'dimensions_html' => '1 x 1 x 1 cm',
  ...
```

Using *"[Additional custom dimensions for products in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49255986/additional-custom-dimensions-for-products-in-woocommerce/49258222#49258222)"* answer code, I created 3 new custom dimensions (depth, diameter, seat-height)…

**Problem:** I want to add these properties to the product class so they are directly available everywhere like:

```
$product = [
  'dimensions' => [
    'length' => 1,
    'width' => 1,
    'height' => 1,
    'depth' => 1,
    'diameter' => 1,
    'seat-height' => 1
  ],
  'dimensions_html' => '1 x 1 x 1 x 1 x 1 x 1 cm',
  ...
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score -1):

I worked around and manipulated the `dimensions_html` instead to include all necessary dimensions. This is not a elegant or universal solution, but works for me right now.

```
// functions.php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_dimensions', 'change_formated_product_dimentions', 10, 2 );
function change_formated_product_dimentions( $dimension_string, $dimensions ){
    global $product;
    $cm = get_option( 'woocommerce_dimension_unit' );

    $html = '';

    if( $dimensions['length'] ){
        $html .= '<span><strong>Length</strong> '.$dimensions['length'].' '.$cm.'</span>';
    }

    if( $dimensions['width'] ){
        $html .= '<span><strong>Width</strong> '.$dimensions['width'].' '.$cm.'</span>';
    }

    if( $dimensions['height'] ){
        $html .= '<span><strong>Height</strong> '.$dimensions['height'].' '.$cm.'</span>';
    }

    $depth = $product->get_meta( '_depth' );
    if( $depth ){
        $html .= '<span><strong>Depth</strong> '.$depth.' '.$cm.'</span>';
    }

    $diameter = $product->get_meta( '_diameter' );
    if( $diameter ){
        $html .= '<span><strong>Diameter</strong> '.$diameter.' '.$cm.'</span>';
    }

    $seat_height = $product->get_meta( '_seat_height' );
    if( $seat ){
        $html .= '<span><strong>Seat height</strong> '.$seat_height.' '.$cm.'</span>';
    }

    return $html;
}
```

This is now included in `$product['dimensions_html']` and, when echoed results in

**Length** 1 cm
  **Width** 1 cm
  **Height** 1 cm
  **Depth** 1 cm
  **Diameter** 1 cm
  **Seat height** 1 cm

and which (almost) just what I wanted.